# How to use List<Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>> to GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dictionary

I have a `List<Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>>` that I want to use as DataSource for a GridView I want to export as Excel file.
But all I see is this:

[image]

How do I display the keys of the dictionary as cell headers and the values as rows?

**Update:**

I changed it to a DataTable.
How do I dynamically fill rows in a DataTable in this case:

```
DataTable exportTable = new DataTable();
            exportTable.Columns.Add("Place", typeof(string));
            exportTable.Columns.Add("Day", typeof(string));
            foreach (var time in timeList)
            {
                exportTable.Columns.Add(time, typeof(string)); 
            }

exportTable.Rows.Add("New York", 1/1/2015, ?, ?, ?, ...);
```

Comment: This is possible if manually building the binding expressions for the columns, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Count is a property on the Dictionary that it can read.  Unfortunately, the grid isn't that flexible to support what you are trying to do.  It would be able to support a DataTable/DataSet structure, so can you convert your Dictionary into a table and bind that?